# CentOS 6.6 Doesn't Boot. Stucks at Enabling local filesystem quotas [ok]

Tags: centos, filesystems, centos6, boot

I am running radius server on my CentOS 6.6, yesterday I tried to reboot my machine with `sudo reboot` with using Putty. It didn't restarted for some reason and I had to go to my DataCenter. When I shut it down and power up, I ran fsck once and rebooted the machine.

Now the system stucks at `Enabling local filesystem quotas [ok]` for some reason. I have live cd and I can reach to my files when I boot it up from live Cd.

How could I find more information about why the system got stuck?

Screenshoot here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1haf.jpg

Comment: Your question is likely to get closed as being too broad. I changed the wording of the broadest part of your question to be more specific. Once you have found relevant data about the state of the system you can ask another question about how to resolve the particular problem (unless the data you collect makes it obvious, what is happening).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Boot to just a command line by adding `init=/bin/bash` to the kernel arguments in the boot loader.
2. Open a shell in a new VT by typing `openvt -- /bin/bash`
3. Continue the original boot sequence by typing `exec /sbin/init` in the first bash shell.

Once the boot sequence stall you can switch to the shell opened by `openvt` and start collecting information about the state of the system state at this point.

A few relevant commands to run in order to find more information could be:

- `ps -fA --forest | less` (in order to see the process tree and hopefully identify which exact command is stuck).
- `dmesg` to see the kernel log, which may contain hints if the system got stuck due to a hardware fault rather than a software problem.
- `ls -lart /var/log` to see which logfile was last written to.

Comment: Thank you very much, sorted out the problem with this method.